# Remote access to MYSQL database - WAMP

Tags: mysql, wamp, remote-access, wampserver

I'm having troubles setting remote access to my WAMP MYSQL database.

To my.ini I added:

```
bind-address=10.0.0.139
```

In the MYSQL log I got:

```
140423 11:12:46 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140423 11:12:46 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140423 11:12:46 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140423 11:12:46 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140423 11:12:46 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140423 11:12:46 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140423 11:12:46 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140423 11:12:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140423 11:12:47 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 8515141
140423 11:12:48 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '10.0.0.139'; port: 3306
140423 11:12:48 [Note]   - '10.0.0.139' resolves to '10.0.0.139';
140423 11:12:48 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '10.0.0.139'.
140423 11:12:48 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140423 11:12:48 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I created a user, that has all privileges:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

I tested the 3306 port with port listener, and the port is opened. Still, I'm unable to connect to my db remotely.

How can I fix that?

Comment: How remote are you? Do you mean another ip on your internal network or from somewhere on the internet (outside your local network)

Comment: From internet, outside local network

Comment: Have you port forwarded your routers port number 3306. If not you will have to to allow unsolicited access via that port.

Comment: Yup - I tried connecting to the port 3306 from external IP, and it works fine. However, I'm still unable to connect to the DB - HeidiSQL says "Can't connect to MYSQL server."

Comment: In that case have you setup an exception in your firewall so it is not blockig port 3306.

Comment: I turned firewall off already.

Comment: Try changing the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`